# Codeigniter setting csrf_protection from controller

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, csrf

When I try to set csrf_protection in codeigniter to true

```
$this->config->set_item('csrf_protection', TRUE);
```

from the controller the token is not generated even if the value is really set to true and in the form the hidden input is set but with the native name value and not with the one I set

```
$this->config->set_item('csrf_cookie_name', 'cookie_direct')
```

like if the security library must be reloaded.

I can't use `$config['csrf_ignore']` because I want the opposite, all the controllers on

```
$config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;
```

or

```
$config['csrf_protection'] = true;
```

with AJAX when the user makes a choice.

Is there any solution?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62265899/2275490

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I need something more automatic because the `csrf token` is already setted it just it was with the native configuration `<input type="hidden" name="ci_csrf_token" value="">` i need it to be with the configuration i defined with  `$this->config->set_item('csrf_cookie_name', 'cookie_direct')`

Comment: `<input type="hidden" name="ci_csrf_token" value="" data-csrf_cookie_name="cookie_direct">` which you can address in ajax call like `$('input[data-csrf_cookie_name="cookie_direct"]')` it's a bit unclear where your difficulty is, so I'm just guessing

Comment: `<input type="hidden" name="ci_csrf_token" value=""> is generated automatically in the for so i want `<input type="hidden" name="csrf_cookie_name" value="csrf_cookie_value"> to be generated automatically in place

Comment: I've just edited your question, I hope it shows what you want to ask, in a better format. Anyway, I'd ask you to describe more detailed your last comment and edit it into the question itself, as it is still quite unclear what you want to achieve or where you are having a problem with. thanks

Comment: thank you very much, what I'am trying to do is like put `$config['csrf_protection']` to `false` and changing it to `TRUE` true a controller or an extended core.
if you check for the value you see that it s correct but if you check html code you find that it was generated with native values

Comment: any other suggestion?